# Virtual TreeView Loop

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I would like to go through ALL the roots of a VirtualTreeView and delete them.

I don't want to clear it.

I get an access violation with this code:

```
var
 Node : PVirtualNode;
begin
 if VirtualStringTree1.GetFirst = NIL then exit;
 Node := NIL;
 repeat
  if Node = NIL then 
   Node := VirtualStringTree1.GetLast 
  else Node:=VirtualStringTree1.GetPrevious (Node);
  if Node <> NIL then VirtualStringTree1.DeleteNode(Node);
 until Node = VirtualStringTree1.GetFirst;
end;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the difference between clearing the list and deleting all the nodes?

Comment: How about RootNodeCount := 0?

Comment: rootnodecount := 0 sounds good too.  The difference is that I need some of the data from the root nodes BEFORE I delete them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a logical error in your implementation: after deleting the node your local variable `Node` points to a non-existing node.

I don't understand why you don't want to just clear the tree, but you could delete all nodes from last to first like this:

```
var
  Node, TmpNode: PVirtualNode;
begin
  Node := Tree.GetLast;
  while Assigned(Node) do
  begin
    TmpNode := Tree.GetPrevious(Node);
    Tree.DeleteNode(Node);
    Node := TmpNode;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: this works like a charm thank you. you're right I totally forgot about that.